# SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as usuario@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

Estoy haciendo el deploy de mi aplicación de ruby on rails.
y me arroja el siguiente error

> SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as
>   usuario@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx : fingerprint d1:81:65:57:08:9f:c5:5b does not
>   match for  "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"
>
> Caused by: Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch: fingerprint d1:81:65:57:08:9f
>   :c5:5b does not match for "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"
>
> Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook => passenger:rvm:hook =>
>   passenger:test_which_passenger (See full trace by running task with
>   --trace)

Hasta donde entiendo la llave de acceso no coincide pero ya genere y la agregue nuevamente al repositorio.

Lo que he podido diagnosticar es que este mismo servidor con la misma dirección ip lo acabo de reinstalar porque me estaba dando otros problemas. Probé cambiando la IP de este servidor y me realizo el deploy sin problema, pero la situación es que tengo que usar necesariamente la ip que me esta dando problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución

el problema era con el archivo **known_hosts** que se encuentra en mi maquina de desarrollo, en mi caso con Windows 7. Este archivo se encuentra en la siguiente dirección

```
C:\Users\nombre_usuario\.ssh
```

Edite el archivo `known_hosts` eliminando la linea de la ip que me estaba dando conflicto y funciono!